# jQuery modal dialogue content error

Tags: jquery

I have a jQuery modal dialogue content as bellow:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   jQuery(
    function() {
     jQuery("#bill")
      .dialog(
       {
        bgiframe: true,
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 350,
        width: 400,
        modal: true
       }
      );
     jQuery('body')
      .bind(
       'click',
       function(e){
        if(
         jQuery('#bill').dialog('isOpen')
         && !jQuery(e.target).is('.ui-dialog, a')
         && !jQuery(e.target).closest('.ui-dialog').length
        ){
         jQuery('#bill').dialog('close');
        }
       }
      );
    }
   );
  </script>
```

this is working fine other than the color code added for font:

```
<span class="label user-label" style="background-color:#09F">

      <a href="Bill_details.php?Bill_id=<?php echo $row_Recordset1['Bill_id'];?>" onclick="jQuery('#bill').load('Bill_details.php?Bill_id=<?php echo $row_Recordset1['Bill_id'];?>').dialog('open');  return false">
      **<font color=white>**<?php echo $row_Recordset1['Bill_date']; ?>**</font>**
      </a>
```

I mean when I added this `<font color=white></font>` that time jQuery Modal is not working.

Comment: The HTML `<font>` tag has been deprecated since 1997. It shouldn't be used anymore. What happens if you change it to a span? Why don't you just set the color of the `<a/>`?

Comment: I tried with <span class="label user-label" style="color:white; background-color:#09F"  > but font color is not working.

Comment: Yes setting color on <a> solve the problem. Thanks for the idea.